# My codes show nothing after clicking 'calculate' in html

Tags: javascript, html

Furthermore,I also realize that the values typed before clicking 'calculate' are disappear also.Until now I still cannot find the errors because I think my formula in calculating mortgage loan is correct.

HTML code:

```
<html>

<head>
    <script src="cal_mortgage.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <table>
        <h2>mortgage calculator:</h2>
        <tr><td>principal</td><td><input type="text" id="principal"/></td></tr>
        <tr><td>interest %</td><td><input type="text" id="interest"/></td></tr>
        <tr><td>term (year)</td><td><input type="text" id="term"/></td></tr><p></p>
        <tr><td><input type="submit" value="calculate" onclick="cal_mortgage()"/></td><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td>monthly payment</td><td><input type="text" id="monthly_pay"/></td></tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>


</html>
```

JavaScript code:

```
function cal_mortgage()

{
    var PR = form.principal.value; /*present value of the mortgage loan*/             
    var IN = (form.interest.value / 100) / 12; /*interest rate of the mortgage loan*/  
    var PE = form.term.value * 12; /*number of periods of the mortgage loan*/  

    var PAY = (PR * IN) / (1 - Math.pow(1 + IN, -PE)); /*regular payment to apply to the mortgage loan*/

    form.monthly_pay.value = PAY; 
}
```

Comment: what are you wanting to do with the calculated value? You're not doing anything with it, and then you're submitting the form anyway.

Comment: change your type="submit" to type="button", do an alert to return the results it should work, if you want to print it somewhere in the page you can follow sshashank's answer

Comment: But I have 'form.monthly_pay.value = PAY;' which assigns 'PAY' to 'form.monthly_pay.value' and I thought the calculated value will be shown up in 'monthly payment' column.(This comment is for sevenseacat)

Comment: What browser do you test?

Comment: I use Google Chrome to test only and this question actually is my JavaScript exercise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your html file, change `<form>` to `<form id="Calculate">` and change button type from submit to button

In your javascript cal_mortgage() function, add this as your first line:

```
form = document.getElementById("Calculate")
```

Now it should work

NEW CODE:

```
function cal_mortgage()

{
    form = document.getElementById('Calculate')
    var PR = form.principal.value; /*present value of the mortgage loan*/             
    var IN = (form.interest.value / 100) / 12; /*interest rate of the mortgage loan*/  
    var PE = form.term.value * 12; /*number of periods of the mortgage loan*/  

    var PAY = (PR * IN) / (1 - Math.pow(1 + IN, -PE)); /*regular payment to apply to the mortgage loan*/

    form.monthly_pay.value = PAY; 
}

<html>
<head>
    <script src="cal_mortgage.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="Calculate">
        <table>
        <h2>mortgage calculator:</h2>
        <tr><td>principal</td><td><input type="text" id="principal"/></td></tr>
        <tr><td>interest %</td><td><input type="text" id="interest"/></td></tr>
        <tr><td>term (year)</td><td><input type="text" id="term"/></td></tr><p></p>
        <tr><td><input type="button" value="calculate" onclick="cal_mortgage()"/></td><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td>monthly payment</td><td><input type="text" id="monthly_pay"/></td></tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, but yours is not really work. After I click'calculate',although  all the things include 'monthly payment' appear but they just flash and then all things disappear again.

Comment: @user3310635, there I changed it. It works for me now

Comment: sorry,I didnt see 'change button type from submit to button' just now,that's why I cannot get the answer.But can I know why 'submit' should be changed to 'button'???

Comment: @user3310635, The submit button is usually used to submit the form values that it currently has to the page that you specify in your form tag. However if you are using javascript, you should use button since it is more dynamic and allows for a more controlled access. If you want to know the specifics look at examples using the two. Submit tends to get used more often with .asp pages and .php files or scripts.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work.  But I haven't checked the mathematics:

```
<html>

<head>
    <script src="cal_mortgage.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <table>
        <h2>mortgage calculator:</h2>
        <tr><td>principal</td><td><input type="text" id="principal" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td>interest %</td><td><input type="text" id="interest" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td>term (year)</td><td><input type="text" id="term" /></td></tr><p></p>
        <tr><td><input type="button" value="calculate" onclick="cal_mortgage()" /></td><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td>monthly payment</td><td><input type="text" id="monthly_pay" /></td></tr>
        </table>
    </form>
<script>
function cal_mortgage()

{
    var PR = document.getElementById("principal").value; /*present value of the mortgage loan*/             
    var IN = (document.getElementById("interest").value / 100) / 12; /*interest rate of the mortgage loan*/  
    var PE = document.getElementById("term").value * 12; /*number of periods of the mortgage loan*/  

    var PAY = (PR * IN) / (1 - Math.pow(1 + IN, -PE)); /*regular payment to apply to the mortgage loan*/

    document.getElementById("monthly_pay").value = PAY; 
}
</script>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Thanks to your answer too and after seeing both of your codes, I only know the wrong part.